# Subfunction and Function exercise

Tags: python, function

This is my exercise: 
create a program with a main function and a separate subfunction called hello, which when called prints "Hello there!". The subfunction does not take any parameters or return any value, just prints the line. Then, to the main function, add a call to the subfunction and two print commands, the first one before the call which says "Lets call the subfunction:", and one after the subfunction call, a print command which prints "Quitting.". If implemented correctly, the program will print the following:

```
>>> 
Lets call the subfunction:
Hello there!
Quitting.
>>>
```

This is my code:

```
def hello():
      print("Hello there!")

def main():
    print("Lets call the subfunction:")
    hello()
    print("Quitting.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But it is not working

Comment: How are your running this? What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: Works fine for me.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "subfunction".

Comment: I'm running the code using Viope, an academic console

Comment: Your code runs fine

Comment: If you are running in an academic console, `__name__ == "__main__"` may not be true.